# D3.js and coordinate system

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying D3, and have some issues. Not sure what is the best way to endure coordinate system.
Please find the source below.

EDIT: Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bW627/)

1. I simulated the inverted coordinate by `yScale -> .range([  height -  padding, padding]);` Instead of `.range([  padding - height -  padding]);` . Is this the best way. If all the objects in the svg needs to be correctly oriented, is it best to apply to the outermost  element?

   `var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")

       .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)

       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

     .append("g") <---`
2. The bigger rectangle ({"X":100, "Y": 100, "W":40, "H": 40}), is outside the axis. So, I am doing something wrong.

Any help to make this graph to contain within the axis, with proper scaling and orientation is highly appreciated.

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Script.js

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left, 
    height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom
    padding = 40; 


var data = [
    {"X":10, "Y": 10, "W":10, "H": 10}, 
    {"X":100, "Y": 100, "W":40, "H": 40}
]

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.X; })])
     .range([padding, width - padding]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Y; })])
     .range([  height -  padding, padding]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" 
            + margin.left  + "," 
            + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.X); }) 
        .attr("y", function (d) { return  yScale(d.Y); })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return  (d.W); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return  (d.H); })

//Create X axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

//Create Y axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re 1.: yes, that is the best way.

Also note that D3 will not save your bacon when you 'flip' a scale like that and then feed widths into it, which will come out negative: when using those for SVG height attributes, those will be flagged as illegal SVG content and the browser will barf a hairball (not show what you want).

Re 2.: once you have corrected your negative widths / heights, then you can prevent 'plotting outside the area' by wrapping your s in a clipping rectangle; this can be done by placing them in a separate group, which is then assigned a clipping rect matching your output area.

For #1, see also in reply to your question to the mailing list:

http://bl.ocks.org/3671490

has all bugs fixed and showing a proper rect.

Style issue: your code would only have worked with a linear axis as you convert width and height via a single call to xScale/yScale instead of calculating the absolute coordinates in domain space first, then convert both via scale to calculate the width / height in output space. To show that the new approach works in log space too, here's a copy of the above gist using log/log scales instead:

http://bl.ocks.org/3671592

The code is 'rough' in that all calculations are explicitly done and no 'invariants' are moved outside the .attr() calls: x1/y1/x2/y2 get calculated several times as each .attr() needs two of them. This sort of thing is usually 'solved' by setting up the data (precalculating / sorting / swapping / whatever is needed) before feeding it to d3.selection.data().

Lesson learned: you need to do more work to be completely scale agnostic when working with SVG; if you want faster code instead, you need to prepare your data so that the output will produce valid SVG (here: 'processed' input = [{X:80,Y:80,W:10,H:-60]]), in particular positive values for  width and height (or similarly x2 > x1 and y2 > y1 for )