# Coordinate translation in d3.js map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a map using the script in this link.
https://bl.ocks.org/sistemawebpro/8ef27771795b451d0589e95e5674aa41

However I found that there is something strange in this code.

This is a part of the coordinate inputs of the map. (Input is contained in the code of the link)

`cities = [{ 'code': 'OTT', 'city': 'OTTAWA', 'country': 'CANADA', 'lat': '23.10', 'lon': '120.34' }, { 'code': 'BSB', 'city': 'BRASILIA', 'country': 'BRAZIL', 'lat': '-32.85', 'lon': '133.30' }]`

Actually, the real latitude and longitude of Ottawa and Brasilia is 45.4/-75.6 and -15.7/-47.9. But this map doesn't use these real coordinates. They use 23.10/120.34 and -32.85/133.30.
Of course, when I used real coordinates as input of this map, the coordinate circles were drawn in wrong place.

But I have no idea how to translate real coordinates into this map's coordinate.

[Put a real coordinate on a map in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651584/put-a-real-coordinate-on-a-map-in-d3-js)

[D3.js and coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323854/d3-js-and-coordinate-system)

I learned that d3.js map's coordinate system can be different from real coordinate system while searching, but I couldn't find how to translate real coordinate.

I even tried to calculate and figure out the translation equation using the input coordinates, but I couldn't....

Is there any way to figure out how to translate real coordinates into this map's coordinates?

Comment: According to: https://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=23.100000&long=120.340000 the lat/ling values for OTTAWA are locating a city in Taiwan. There might be a problem with the data

Comment: I would be weary of using this example. There are many d3 examples using regular lat longs - the only unit that should be paired with a d3 geoprojection (there shouldn't be the need for prior transformations - I believe the author is trying to overlay the points on an image by tinkering with projection and units, but I don't have the time to look into it at the moment; however, the proper way would be to set the projection to match the projection used to make the image and then use regular lat longs).